# How can I read the whole row data from SQLite with FMDB in IOS dev?

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I can read all column Data from code like this ...

```
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT Name, Age, FROM PersonList"];

while ([rs next]) {

NSString *name = [rs stringForColumn:@"Name"];

int age = [rs intForColumn:@"Age"];

}
```

or find some Data from this way

```
NSString *address = [db stringForQuery:@"SELECT Address FROM PersonList WHERE Name = ?",@"John"];
```

But if I want a Array contents the whole row's data(assume all my row data is a simple String)

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a *resultDict* method defined on the *FMResultSet* class. I would do it like this:

```
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT Name, Age, FROM PersonList"];
while ([rs next]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [[rs resultDict] description]);
}
```

This should print something like:

```
{
    Name = bbbbbird1;
    Age = 25;
}
```

for every row in the PersonList table. Now there are two ways of putting these values into the array. One is to use *allValues* method of *NSDictionary*, however the order of the columns will most probably be broken. The other way is to build the array yourself:

```
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT Name, Age, FROM PersonList"];
while ([rs next]) {
    NSMutableArray* rowData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0; i<[s columnCount]; i++) {
        [rowData addObject:[[rs resultDict] objectForKey:[[rs columnNameForIndex:i] lowercaseString]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", [rowData description]);
}
```

The above should print:

```
(
    bbbbbird1,
    25
)
```

I hope this is what you are looking for. You can put this code in the *FMResultsSet* category if you need to have the rows as arrays in many places in you app.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is great but there is an elegant way to achieve the example the OP gave:

```
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:customQuery];
while ([rs next]) {
   NSString* tempName = [rs objectForColumnName:@"someColumnName"];
}
```

According to the [objectForColumnName](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMResultSet.html#//api/name/objectForColumnName:) documentation the return value:

> Either NSNumber, NSString, NSData, or NSNull. If the column was NULL, this returns [NSNull null] object.

So it can be achieved with a single method (assuming you know the type of your DB).

Also, if you are looking for a custom array that contains class objects you can combine them both:

```
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:customQuery];
while ([rs next]) {
   someCustomClassName *tempClass = [[someCustomClassName alloc] init];
   [tempClass setSomePropertyValue:[rs objectForColumnName:@"someColumnName"];
   [someArray addObject:tempClass]];
}
```